# Div overflow does not align correct

Tags: html, css

How can I make the second line be one line and not broken up as it is now?

[image]

And look like this:

[image]

I tried to use the `display: table` and `table-cell` but it makes no difference.

I never seem to get along with CSS.

css:

```
<style>

.column1 {
    float: left;
    width: 10%;
    font-size: 350%;
}
.column2 {
    float: left;
    width: 10%;
    font-size: 350%;
}
.column3 {
    float: left;
    width: 80%;
    font-size: 350%;
}


</style>
```

html:

```
<div class="row" style="display: table">
  <div class="column1" style="background-color:#ccc;" display: table-cell;>
    <b>col1</b><br>
    <div style="background-color:#FF0000;">32</div>
    <div style="background-color:#00FF00;">33</div>
  </div>
  <div class="column2" style="background-color:#ccc;" display: table-cell;>
    <b>col2</b><br>
    <div style="background-color:#FF0000;">11:00</div>
    <div style="background-color:#00FF00;">12:00</div>  
  </div>
  <div class="column3" style="background-color:#ccc;" display: table-cell;>
    <b>col3</b><br>
    <div style="background-color:#FF0000;">This is some text That will overflow the div by a few words</div>
    <div style="background-color:#00FF00;">Next line</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: You're using the HTML table layout and floats combined, I'd suggest sticking with one or the other.

Comment: I guess you can use the `<table>` itself for this?

Comment: @JonesJoseph I tried table but It I could not get the font size large enough.

Comment: you need to arrange you data in rows, not columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use "table CSS" you might aswell adjust the markup. I made an example here

**[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/roe6saq9/1/)**

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

th {
    background-color: white;
}

tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #00FF00;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #FF0000;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>col1</th>
    <th>col2</th>
    <th>col3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>31</td>
    <td>11:00</td>
    <td>This is some text That will overflow the div by a few words</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>32</td>
    <td>12:00</td>
    <td>Next line</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This is "good enough", it's not meant to be a pretty just work. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I was able to achieve it. To achieve word wrap properly, we need to use `display:table-row` as well

CSS:

```
.column1 {
    float: left;
    width: 10%;
    font-size: 350%; //100%
}
.column2 {
    float: left;
    width: 10%;
    font-size: 350%; //100%
}
.column3 {
    float: left;
    width: 80%;
    font-size: 350%; //100%
}
.row1 {
    background-color:#ccc; 
    display: table-row;
}
.row2 {
    display: table-row;
    background-color:#FF0000;
}
.row3 {
    display: table-row;
    background-color:#00FF00;
}
```

HTML

```
<div style= "display: table;">
  <div class= "row1">
    <div class= "column1" style= "display:table-cell"><b>col1</b></div>
    <div class= "column2" style= "display:table-cell"><b>col2</b></div>
    <div class= "column3" style= "display:table-cell"><b>col3</b></div>
  </div>
  <div class= "row2">   
    <div class= "column1" style="display:table-cell">32</div>
    <div class= "column2" style= "display:table-cell">11:00</div>
     <div class= "column3" style= "display:table-cell">This is some text That will overflow the div by a few words</div>
  </div>
  <div class= "row3">
   <div class= "column1" style= "display:table-cell">33</div>
   <div class= "column2" style= "display:table-cell">12:00</div>  
    <div class= "column3" style="display:table-cell">Next line</div>
  </div>
```

Demo Link: http://jsfiddle.net/5qc7adf9/1/show/
It will display properly only in full screen result window as font size is 350% here. To view it properly in result window of jsfiddle, we would need to reduce font-size.